# how to create a wsdl file for using soap server in java

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui, wsdl2java

How to create a simple Wsdl file for using the soap server in java and then later use it for soap ui for testing web services. Just a simple example.

Comment: want to create a wsdl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a sample Java webservice then use a jdk tool called 'wsgen' to generate the associated wsdl, or use one of the webservice api's like axis2. Look into [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html) guide on how to use the tool